# What if I want to compare multiple conditions when writing sql statements?

Tags: mysql

I want to get all the overlapping rows from the t_match table by comparing the last row in the u_match table with multiple rows in the t_match table.

To get the last row of the u_match row, an sql statement called 'order by id desc limit 1' is used. If you write the following using this, only 1 row is fetched even though there are 2 overlapping rows in t_match. What should I do?

```
SELECT select_id, t.face, t.area, t.day, t.time, t.free 
FROM t_match t, u_match u 
WHERE t.face=u.face and t.area=u.area and t.day=u.day 
      and t.time=u.time and t.free=u.free order by id desc limit 1;
```

Below is the u_match table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpDAg.png)

Below is the t_match table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b8z7.png)

It is the condition that id=2 of u_match and t_match select_id 1 and 3 overlap.

In another way, I wrote the following sql statement, but an error occurs because there are multiple conditions in the where statement. What should I do when I want to compare multiple conditions like that?

```
select select_id, face, area, day, time, free
from t_match
where face and area and day and time and free like 
      (select face, area, day, time, free
       from u_match
       order by id desc limit 1);
```

sampledata (u_match, t_match)

[u_match table]

| id | face | area | day | time | free |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | seoul | mon | 9 | free |
| 2 | 1 | daegu | sun | 10 | free |

[t_match table]

| select_id | t_id | title | face | area | day | time | free |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | no | no | 1 | daegu | sun | 10 | free |
| 2 | no | no | 1 | seoul | mon | 9 | free |
| 3 | no | no | 1 | daegu | sun | 10 | free |

[desired result]

| select_id | face | area | day | time | free |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | daegu | sun | 10 | free |
| 3 | 1 | daegu | sun | 10 | free |

Comment: Please add sample data and desired outcome as text

Comment: Added to post..!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bfac2f6b6e7bd2b6e56a5187a0b3ae1)

```
select t.select_id, u.face, u.area, u.day, u.time, u.free
from (
    select face, area, day, time, free
    from u_match 
    order by id desc limit 1
) u
join t_match t on u.face = t.face 
              and u.area = t.area 
              and u.day = t.day 
              and u.time = t.time 
              and u.free = t.free;
```

Comment: @jixnww youre welcome. Kindly mark this answer as useful if this has solved your problem!